# What's the best way to create a generic serializer which is able to serialize all the subclasses of the base model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, notifications

I'm currently working on a notification system which is going to deliver many different types of notifications through an API.

I have a base notification class called `BaseNotification`. Here is the code:

```
class BaseNotification(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And I want to subclass this model to create different variations of notifications:

```
class InvitationNotification(BaseNotification):
    invited_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campagin = models.ForeignKey(Campagin, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ... the rest of specific fields

class ChatMessageNotification(BaseNotification):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chat_room = models.ForeignKey(SomeSortOfChatRoomWhichIsNotImplementedYet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ... the rest of specific fields
```

As you can see, each of those variations, has some meta-data associated with it. The front-end developer would be able to create user interactions using these meta data (for example, in the case of a chat message, the front-end developer would redirect the user to the chat room)

I want to list all of these notifications through one unified API. For that, I need a serializer to serialize the objects as json but I don't want to have a sperate serializer for each. Ideally I want to have a generalized serializer which is capable of serializing all kinds of notifications and generates different json output depending on the type of the notification object passed in. (It might use other serializers under the hood).

Maybe I'm on the wrong track but the end goal is to deliver notifications and all their meta-data through one unified API.

I really need your suggestions and help. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out by myself. My end goal was to provide some metadata for the front-end developer so that he can implement user interactions based on the type of the notification.

I simply solved the problem with a `JSONField`. That works just fine and that was the only thing I needed.

### models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    NEW_MEMBER_JOINED = 'NEW_MEMBER_JOINED'
    INVITATION = 'INVITATION'
    TEXT = 'TEXT'
    NEW_POST_CREATED = 'NEW_POST_CREATED'
    NEW_MESSAGE = 'NEW_MESSAGE'
    NEW_CAMPAIGN_CONTENT = 'NEW_CAMPAIGN_CONTENT'
    NEW_COMMENT = 'NEW_COMMENT'
    
    target = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notifications')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    metadata = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"[{self.type}] {self.text}"
```

### serializers.py

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = [
            'text', 'type', 'metadata', 'date_created', 'seen'
        ]
```

In my case, this solution works the best.